# Reversing order of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, sorting

The following code rearranges elements by the attribute "amount". How can I alter this code so the items will be reversed? Thanks.

```
var parent = $('#items');
var children = $('a', parent);
children.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt($(a).attr('amount')) - parseInt($(b).attr('amount'));
})

$.each(children, function(i, child) {
    parent.append(child);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the values you are comparing (`b-a` instead of `a-b`):

```
var children = $('a', parent).sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt($(b).attr('amount'), 10) - parseInt($(a).attr('amount'), 10);
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the radix parameter on parseInt, e.g.  parseInt($(b).attr('amount'), 10)

Comment: `$.fn.sort` does not return an array, it returns the jQuery wrapped set again, which does not contain a `reverse` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use prepend instead of append?

http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend#content

Answer (score 1):

I've used this technique.  It's ideal for small collections.

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = function() {
   return this.pushStack(this.get().reverse(), arguments);
};

var r = $('.class').reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
children.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt($(a).attr('amount')) < parseInt($(b).attr('amount')) ? 0 : 1;
});
```